# SIM800l - Disable "SMS Ready" and "Call Ready" unsolicited messages

Tags: stm32, at-command, keil, sim800

My problem is related to SIM800 connection messages.

I use the module with STM32 developlment board. Sometimes module is reporting **SMS Ready** and **Call Ready** messages respectively. When I start to send AT commands to the module, it may send these messages (it doesn't happens all the times).

However, the commands I previously sent are apparently unrelated (for example HTTP commands), and *SMS Ready* / *Call Ready* messages is coming while they are not expected.

Because of this reason, Keil is reporting `"Can not access"` message in the debug session. Is it possible that disabling these messages when the connection is established? Or it means that module has an unexpected reset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [SIM800x modules AT commands guide](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf), **SMS ready** and **Call ready** are URCs (unsolicited result codes) sent at startup as soon as the capabilities to deal with SMS and to perform calls respectively are correctly initialized and available.

So this is the first bad news for you: if you see them it probably means that your device reset due to a bug or as a consequence of one of the commands you previously provided.

The second bad news is that on the AT command guide linked above there's no mention of the capability to disable **SMS Ready** URC.

---

There's fortunately at least a good news: **Call ready** can be disabled by means of **AT+CIURC** command:

> **AT+CIURC**  (Enable or Disable Initial URC Presentation)
>
> *Syntax:* **AT+CIURC=<mode>**
>
> **<mode>** : **0** Disable  URC  presentation - **1** Enable  URC  presentation
>
> **Note:** When module is powered on and initialization procedure is over URC "Call Ready" will be presented if  is 1.

The guide also mentions the fact that this setting is saved in the *profile area*. So, in order to make sure it is persistent to reboot, after issuing the command store active profile:

```
AT&W
OK
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I suppose that disabling Call Ready will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

For me, receiving a lot of messagens Call and SMS ready was a problem on current not enough to keep the module working.

(You can check it too watching the led blinking, if it blinks 6/7 times and stop for a while and restart over again, you have the same problem)

Just to SIM800 keep working is necessary at least 700mA.
Ps.: You can connect directly to your battery 18650 (3.7V-4.2V).

If you are using TP4056 module, you must remember there is 1A max current. try to connect in parallel more than 1 TP4056.